# RequestsDependencyWarning while importing python packages

Tags: python

I am new to python. Was facing an issue while running a python script as below.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.25.1-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.6) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

I tried upgrading the requests and packages but no luck. Please assist me with this problem.