# "RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!" in Azure DevOps - Azure IoT Edge Task - build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-iot-edge

One of my deployment pipelines on Azure DevOps fails when executing the *build module images* action of Azure IoT Edge task. I am trying to deploy a custom module developed using the Azure IoT SDK for C# (.NET 6).

Error message:

`##[error]/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!`

I tried to include [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155627/requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-25-2-or-chardet-3-0-4-doesnt-match-a-s) as CmdLine task before the build task. It worked a few runs and then failed again.

The pipeline already had a "Temporary fix" installing iotedgedev separately as a workaround for [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14167)

The deployment logs don't tell much about where to focus. I wonder what could be the cause of this issue? and if there is a quick fix or something to avoid while developing the application (i.e. warning messages while building or something like that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155627/requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-25-2-or-chardet-3-0-4-doesnt-match-a-s)

Comment: @Rumbles I tried to include that same solution as CmdLine task before the Build task. It worked for a few runs and then failed again. So the workaround doesn't tackle entirely the original cause of the problem. It doesn't answer my question :(

Comment: Did you add that step to your build process? It sounds like it has created a new venv or is running on a new machine that still has the wrong version of the library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -> force pyOpenSSL to version 22.0.0
(Edited 09.01.20223)

> pip install -U iotedgedev pyOpenSSL==22.0.0 urllib3 requests

The cause seems to be a reported bug related to a dependency issue connected to a new pyOpenSSL release: [github.com/Azure/iotedgedev/issues/589](https://github.com/Azure/iotedgedev/issues/589)

pyOpenSSL>=20.0.1 on iotedgedev requirements resolves pyOpenSSL-22.1.0 creating some conflict with urlib or chardet

In this case, a temporary fix needed a "quick" temporary fix :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. After checking previous success Pipelines it seems that then new iotedgedev version 3.3.5 has a problem in DevOps Build Task (I haven't investigate more)

To fix that, at least temporally, I have added a Command Line Script **before** Build Modules Images Task that installs version 3.3.4.

> pip install -U iotedgedev==3.3.4

It has worked for me, but as I said is a temporally patch.

Comment: Short answer: use pip install -U iotedgedev pyOpenSSL==22.0.0 But your answer makes a lot of sense, I checked previous runs and the iotedgedev version changed 3.3.4 -> 3.3.5 but surprisingly forcing 3.3.4 didn't solve the problem. Tried changing to ubuntu 18.04, it worked but took twice the time to deploy.  The problem seems to be related to a new pyOpenSSL release:  https://github.com/Azure/iotedgedev/issues/589

Comment: You are right, I used version 3.3.4 and worked, but suddenly it started to fail again. I did the same with version 3.3.3 and the result was the same. Installing iotedge with pyOpenSSL==22.0.0 works again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As this appears to happen [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73199376/2303098) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71199020/2303098) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68458230/2303098) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68172221/2303098) (in different flavours), I felt it made sense to explain why this happens. It's right there in the error message actually, in my case:

```
.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:102:
 RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.9) or 
 chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.12) doesn't match a supported version!
```

So, apparently the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) package needs its dependencies at a certain version level to work correctly. But `pip` doesn't show *which* versions:

```
$ pip show requests | grep Requires
Requires: certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3
```

Let's look at [**init**.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.27.x/requests/__init__.py#L57) then, this is where the error occured:

```
    if chardet_version:
        major, minor, patch = chardet_version.split(".")[:3]
        major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
        # chardet_version >= 3.0.2, < 5.0.0
        assert (3, 0, 2) <= (major, minor, patch) < (5, 0, 0)
```

....and on it goes, and we can now fiddle around with the expected version strings until the warning goes away or update the `requests` package to a version that accepts its required packages at the [correct versions](https://github.com/psf/requests/commit/73793ce43e3d940a0f8d6b9b8ff125617828d8a1).

TL;DR: One has to upgrade or downgrade the affected packages (`request` or its dependencies) to get it right, or fiddle around with `requests/__init__.py` until the warning goes away :-)